# string in circle format in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ipad, iphone-sdk-3.0, cgcontext

is it possible to to draw a string in CGContext in circle path (like circle instead of line)?

Comment: Do you mean a text bending along a circle path ?

Answer (score 0):

Look in the developer documentation for the "Circle View" demo application. It draws a string in a circle. It's a desktop application, but you should be able to adapt it.